# CTE partition not returning the correct row number - TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the latest file in a list of files using CTE. So far I have this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, TRISPATH, Document, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Document) AS RN
    FROM 
        LinkedDocuments
)
SELECT 
    ID, Document, RN 
FROM 
    CTE 
WHERE 
    TRISPATH IS NOT NULL --AND RN!=1
```

It seems to work with some of the IDs it returns what I want, however some of them (around 30%) don't start at 1, they start at a random number based on the ID:

```
14  J:\PRS\CVs\Original CVs\2015\N\*****, ***** CL Oct 15.txt   11
14  J:\PRS\CVs\Original CVs\2015\N\*****, ***** CV Nov 15.pdf   12
14  J:\PRS\CVs\Original CVs\2015\N\*****, ***** CV Oct 15.docx  13
```

I cant seem to figure out why this is happening, I'm sure its something to do with the partition but I can't figure out what.

Comment: You need to find a way to order each partition by date.  Is there a document date timestamp column available?

Comment: Ideally i would, but this database i really badly designed, the only columns in this table are ID (relative to the person the document is linked to) Document Type (1 of 3 values) and Document, they are all primary keys. with the dates most of them are in the format shown above but not all of them.

Comment: Does every document end in `CV Nov 15.ext` ?

Comment: More or less yes 182k out of 188k. based on: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LinkedDocuments WHERE document LIKE '%CV ___ __.%' OR document like '%CL ___ __.%' AND TRISPATH IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have records where TRISPATH is null, they will be assigned a row number and then be filtered out in the final select.

To ensure row numbers start at 1, move the WHERE clause to the CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, TRISPATH, Document, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Document) AS RN
    FROM LinkedDocuments
    WHERE TRISPATH IS NOT NULL 
)
SELECT ID,Document, RN FROM CTE
```